# How do you specify the path of 'function.json' for Azure Functions?

Tags: azure-functions

When using the [script model](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script) with Azure Functions coupled with a deployment from Git, how does one specify where Azure Function should expect the file `function.json` to be found? In particular, how Git repositories with multiple projects, and possibly multiple files `function.json` are expected to be handled through this deployment model for the Azure Functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each Function has a separate folder with `function.json` file inside. (No `s` in the end of file name).

See lots of examples in [this repository](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/tree/master/sample).